# Pagedown app always converts first line at <code> tag?

Tags: javascript, javascript-marked

I added script for converting text to markdown display. Added "content-markdown" class to my div of content but my first line of the text always is being surrounded by `<pre>` and `<code>` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content-markdown").each(function(){
        var content =  $(this).text()
        var markedContent = marked(content)
        console.log(markedContent)
        $(this).html(markedContent)
})
</script>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Could we see the `marked` function body?

Comment: I didnt change code of marked function. It's automatically added with app which I installed via pip and added Jquery min in head.